# Prevent Smooch from adding me to Slack channel

Tags: slack, smooch

I added the [Slack integration](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/business-systems/#slack) to my [Smooch](https://smooch.io) account and I keep being added to the customer-generated channels (i.e. `#customer-name`).

I only want to be in my specified channel (i.e. `#general`) as I am not the one of the team doing customer support and I don't want to receive all these notifications.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creator of a Slack channel is always automatically invited to that channel. Smooch creates Slack channels on behalf of the user who authorized the integration, so they will always be automatically invited to the created channels. Your options would be to have someone else from your team integrate Slack, or to create a dummy user in your Slack team that will serve as the integration owner